# Unity3D for Android and iOS: GUI Tutorial or free GUI Manager alternatives to EZ GUI and NGUI

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, android-layout, unity-game-engine

What do you think is the best way to develop a GUI for mobile devices in Unity3D? Especially with Android, it's so many different resolutions. I would like that the GUI looks the same on each devices. Is there free plugins or good scripting tutorials? Or it's just really good with NGUI or EZ GUI? Unfortunately I have no experience with the two GUI Managers. Which is better for mobile GUI development? Is there a way to differentiate ldpi, mdpi and hdpi devices like in Android SDK?

Comment: did you check out the Video Tutorials for NGUI? they are very great, there is also one for different screen sizes. http://www.tasharen.com/?page_id=197

Comment: Thank you, I chose Ngui.